# order by is not working for me in sequelize-typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, sequelize.js, nestjs, sequelize-typescript

I'm new to nestjs and sequelize-typescript ,
here i'm trying to execute this below Query when i do this 
without the order property i'm getting result but
Getting error when try to run this with order by property like this
**Error: Unable to find a valid association for model,'cardStep'**

**Inside my service i'm using this function to fetch all card details**

```
    async fetchSubReports(id:string):Promise<any>{
        try {
            const report = await this.cardRepository.findAll<Card>({
                include:[{
                    model:cardStep,
                    attributes: {
                        exclude: ['createdAt','updatedAt','cardId']
                    },
                    include:[{
                        model:Counter,
                        attributes: {
                            exclude: ['createdAt','updatedAt','cardId','stepId']
                        },
                    }]
                }],
                where: {id},
                order: [[ cardStep,'order','DESC']],                
            });
            return report;
        } catch (err) {
            console.log({err})
            return {};
        }
    }
```

**here my schema**
*Even I checked the type of the order attribute it's in integer value*

```
import {
    Table,
    Column,
    Model,
    PrimaryKey,
    ForeignKey,
    DataType,
    BelongsTo,
    HasOne,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';

import { Card } from 'src/card/card.entity';
import { Counter } from 'src/counter/counter.entity';

@Table({
    tableName: 'card_step',
    timestamps: true,
})

export class cardStep extends Model {
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column({
        type: DataType.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4,
    })
    id: string

    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    stepTitle: string

    @PrimaryKey
    @Column({ allowNull: false ,unique: 'unique_order'})
    order: number

    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    draft: boolean

    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    time: string

    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    date: string

    @PrimaryKey
    @ForeignKey(() => Card)
    @Column({ type: DataType.UUID ,unique: 'unique_order'})
    cardId: string

    @BelongsTo(() => Card)
    reports: Card

    @HasOne(()=>Counter)
    counters: Counter[]

}
```

**card model**

```
import {
    Table,
    Column,
    Model,
    DataType,
    PrimaryKey,
    ForeignKey,
    BelongsTo,
    HasMany,
} from 'sequelize-typescript';

import { Client } from '../client/client.entity';
import { cardStep } from 'src/card-step/card-step.entity';
import { Counter } from 'src/counter/counter.entity';

@Table({
    tableName: 'cards',
    timestamps: true,
})

export class Card extends Model {

    @PrimaryKey
    @Column({
        type: DataType.UUID,
        defaultValue: DataType.UUIDV4,
    })
    id: string

    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    title: string

    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    sendTo: string

    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    sendAnswersTo: string

    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    startDate: string

    @Column({ allowNull: false })
    endDate: string

    @ForeignKey(() => Client)
    @Column({ type: DataType.UUID })
    clientId: string

    @BelongsTo(() => Client)
    user: Client

    @HasMany(() => cardStep)
    subReports: cardStep[]

    @HasMany(() => Counter)
    counters: Counter[]

}
```

**sample output without using orderby**

```
[
  {
    "id": "cd3bd45c-69d6-4d1a-84b2-057a19bc19a8",
    "title": "diwali",
    "sendTo": "hemant soni",
    "sendAnswersTo": "Guys let's celebrate the party",
    "startDate": "01-01-203",
    "endDate": "02-01-2023",
    "clientId": "b995c472-733b-404f-879f-d7b7c970f2c1",
    "createdAt": "2022-11-01T06:14:26.438Z",
    "updatedAt": "2022-11-01T06:14:26.438Z",
    "subReports": [
      {
        "id": "fccc8c82-2f28-4911-b5ed-859d196ac585",
        "stepTitle": "Adults and childern",
        "order": 0,
        "draft": true,
        "time": "06:55",
        "date": "01-01-2023",
        "counters": {
          "id": "0348ab0a-da77-4cdd-995f-4e9f20d1ba6f",
          "attendees": null,
          "children": 10,
          "adults": 50,
          "boys": null,
          "girls": null,
          "over18": null,
          "under18": null,
          "over60": null
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "61a78423-0093-4e43-bdb3-5e9b4ac35211",
        "stepTitle": "Adults and childern",
        "order": 1,
        "draft": true,
        "time": "06:55",
        "date": "01-01-2023",
        "counters": {
          "id": "3da1dffc-48ed-482a-9a84-9dfcb77aaa39",
          "attendees": null,
          "children": 10,
          "adults": 50,
          "boys": null,
          "girls": null,
          "over18": null,
          "under18": null,
          "over60": null
        }
      },
      {
        "id": "6ccf73d2-d2d9-405f-be9e-e9c16fab6b44",
        "stepTitle": "Adults and childern",
        "order": 5,
        "draft": true,
        "time": "06:55",
        "date": "01-01-2023",
        "counters": {
          "id": "5723b054-822f-457d-93cf-384e47684a76",
          "attendees": null,
          "children": 10,
          "adults": 50,
          "boys": null,
          "girls": null,
          "over18": null,
          "under18": null,
          "over60": null
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: What is `subReports`?

Comment: hai @Anatoly subReports contains hasMany cardStep id's which it's populate card_step table datas based on the card id. Inside the card table added this association `@HasMany(() => cardStep) subReports: cardStep[]`

Comment: Please add `Card` model definition as well

Comment: @Anatoly i have added Card schema can you check that .

Comment: Looks like good. Can you add the content of `assocaitions` prop of the Card model at runtime right before `findAll` call?

Comment: thanks for your help @Anatoly i have got the answer this resolves my issue `order: [[ sequelize.literal('"subReports.order"'),'DESC']],`

Comment: even this one is better `order: [[{model: cardStep, as: 'subReports'},'order','desc']],` now i getting how it actually works it's pointing out my alias name of the association .when try with different name the result hasn't come as i expected but if declared with my association name boom it's works...

Comment: You also can try `sequelize.col` instead of a more generic `sequelize.literal`

Answer (score 0):

In your service you just jave to do it like this:

```html
order: [[ 'cardStep','order','DESC']],
```